# Gradle Command Line Properties

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso, gradlew

If I am using gradle command line to run our Android Espresso test cases like this:

```
./gradlew pixel4api31DebugAndroidTest 
-Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.aaa.bbb.Suites.CITestSuite 
-Pandroid.experimental.androidTest.numManagedDeviceShards=2
```

Where can I find documentation on what other possible options exist? i.e
Instead of numManagedDeviceShards, what other options exist that I could pass via command line?

```
-Pandroid.experimental.androidTest.   whatElseCanGoHere
```

or

```
-Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.   whatElseCanGoHere
```

Comment: Not sure about all the android test related options but you can start here
https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line
The other options would be more generic I guess so check here https://developer.android.com/studio/build and here https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html

I'd focus on specific tasks you want to accomplish and look for answers for those.